# .NET WebApi see raw request

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a

```
public void Post([FromBody]Record value)
```

-method that I can call from fiddler with some json.

When calling the method from my mac using WizTools RESTClient 3.1 with the same json, the `value` is always `null`. It looks like it does not get parsed or something.

I'm using `Content-Type: application/json` on both machines and I have double-checked that the `Request.Content` object the headers in the Visual Studio debugger.

If I use a simpler object with only 2 properties like so:

```
public class Test123 {
  public string name { get; set; }
  public int age { get; set; }
}

public void Post([FromBody]Test123 value)
```

I can call it from both fiddler and the mac and the `value` is never null.

So any tips on how to debug this? Is there for instance any way for me to see the raw response sent from my mac to iis/visual studio on my PC? It does not show up in fiddler.

Comment: On a Mac, you can use Charles Proxy for debugging http (equivalent to Fiddler)

Answer (score 7):

For your action method, if you send a request with `Content-Type: application/json` and the request message body of `{"name":"john", "age":20}`, it should correctly bind. BTW, you do not need to use `[FromBody]`, since `Test123` is a complex type.

Anyways, you can view the raw request message by adding a message handler like this.

```
public class MyHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
                                             HttpRequestMessage request,
                                                CancellationToken token)
    {
        HttpMessageContent requestContent = new HttpMessageContent(request);
        string requestMessage = requestContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        return await base.SendAsync(request, token);
    }
}
```

Add the handler like this `config.MessageHandlers.Add(new MyHandler());` in `WebApiConfig.cs` `Register` method. Raw request will be in `requestMessage` variable. You can inspect by breaking there while debugging or write to a trace, etc.

Comment: Just add request.Content = new StringContent(requestMessage.Substring(requestMessage.IndexOf("{")), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"); so as to not interfere with the proceeding chain.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must inform the `content-type` on the http header request. For sample, if you want to pass a `json` format, in the header you have to add:

`Content-Type: application/json`

And in the Body:

```
{ name: "John", Age: 20 }
```

You will get the Test123 object create by the model binder of asp.net mvc web api.

I like to use [`Fiddler`](http://fiddler2.com/) software to make requests manually, and you also can see the raw request/response, create requests with any http verb, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature called "Failed Request Tracing" on IIS (not IIS Express or Kestrel). This feature will show you the detailed logs for any request/response cycle that passes your filter criteria.

**Here is what the output log looks like:**

[image]

**To Enable this feature:**

1. **Start -> Run -> type in "inetmgr"** [ this will open up the IIS management UI]
2. **At the server level Enable FTW and add rules** 
   [image]
3. **Add a rule** ( you can add HTTP 200 code as filter to trace successful request, or some other code - as you see fit)[image]
4. **Last step - I promise - Each site will need to "opt-in" to this feature**[image]

Thats it.. now do your thing and go to the folder with the logs, sort by time. You should see a new log entry that was created around the time of your testing.

Good Luck!!!